# Null pointer in selenium moveTo() but I cannot figure out what is null

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception

I am using Page Object in Selenium with Java.  One element I have is this:

```
private static final String ACTION_TABLE_X = "//table";
private static final String ACTION_HEAD_X = ACTION_TABLE_X + "/thead";
private static final String ACTION_BODY_X = ACTION_TABLE_X + "/tbody";
private static final String ACTION_HEADERS_X = ACTION_HEAD_X + "//th";
private static final String ACTION_ROWS_X = ACTION_BODY_X + "/tr";

@FindBy(xpath = ACTION_ROWS_X)
private List<WebElement> actionRows;
```

later in my code I have a valid row (index == 0):

```
WebElement row = actionRows.get(index);
```

from Selenium debugger for row: **"[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (82fecb3b30e16fcd24a9ab0e4f0478da)] -> xpath: //table/tbody/tr]"**
(which shows row is not null and not "proxy for :::)

I create an action

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(signButton).click().build().perform();
    return getPage(driver, DocuSignDocumentSignaturePage.class);
```

again from debugger for driver: **ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (82fecb3b30e16fcd24a9ab0e4f0478da)**

and after doing this, for action: **org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions@46ab18da**

so in short my driver is non-null, my element is non-null and my action is non null.  However, when I do a

```
action.moveToElement(signButton).click().build().perform();
```

I get a null pointer error.  Highlighting just action..(signButton) shows a null pointer

I can't figure out why since nothing is null.  My original idea was just do do

```
signButton.click()
```

but though I verified the xpath was right, it was clicking on a filter button farther up the page and not even in my rows.

and of course if action.moveToElement(signButton) returns null, then
action.moveToElement(signButton).click() will throw the error.

Anyone understand what is happening?  (This is from DocuSign in case that makes any difference).

====

adding html for the button:

```
<button class="btn ng-binding btn-primary" ng-class="{
            'btn-primary': $props.current.main,
            'btn-secondary': !$props.current.main }" ng-click="component.trigger($props.current.key)" data-qa="status-action-button-sign">
        Sign
    </button>
```

Comment: can you share the html for the page or table? why are using action class? why do you want to click on row instead of td ?

Comment: I will attempt to edit the above and add the html.  But I think the less and greater than will get replaced unless I replace everything with lt and gt.  And using action because the normal selenium click clicked elsewhere, though it shouldn't have.

Comment: what is the locator value for the button you have used?

Comment: //table/tbody/tr[1]//button[contains(text(), 'Sign') and contains(@class, 'btn-primary')]

Comment: Actually, the value of actionRow is //table/tbody/tr[1] and I use it to do a findby of  //button[contains(text(), 'Sign') and contains(@class, 'btn-primary')] and I see maybe my problem is it should be .//button[contains(text(), 'Sign') and contains(@class, 'btn-primary')].  Not sure that would make a difference though since this is the first occurrence anyway?

Comment: I switched to the following which works, but I do not know why the others didn't:

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", signButton);

Comment: action.moveToElement(signButton).click().build().perform(); needs to be changed as actions.moveToElement(signButton).click().build().perform();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks, you haven't used the Actions class Object correctly(used  action.moveToElement instead of  actions.moveToElement).

Please check with the below

`action.moveToElement(signButton).click().build().perform();` needs to be changed as `actions.moveToElement(signButton).click().build().perform();`

else

To avoid the mistake you can change the Object name as below

```
Actions builder= new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(signButton).click().build().perform();
return getPage(driver, DocuSignDocumentSignaturePage.class);
```

Comment: gee.  Hit me in the head ;-)  Sometimes something is so obvious you just don't see it and someone else has to see it ;-)  Thanks

Comment: Yeah no worries:) Sometimes mistake will happen. Please give the upvote...